# Properties of metric spaces

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $C^1 ([0,1])$ be the space of continuous functions in $[0,1]$, differentiable in $(0,1)$ and the derivable can be extended with continuity in $[0,1]$. Also let $\Vert \cdot \Vert c^1: C^1([0.1]) \rightarrow \Bbb R $ defined by  
 
$ \Vert u \Vert c^1 := \Vert u \Vert_\infty + \Vert u' \Vert_\infty \space \forall u \in C^1([0,1]).$ 
Demonstrate if $(C^1([0,1]),\Vert \cdot \Vert c^1)$: 
(a) is a normed space; 
(b) is a compact space; 
(c) is a complete space.

---

I don't really know how to do that, I know the definition from my book but I don't know how to use them to solve those problems.

(a) A normed space is a pair $(X,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ such that $X$ is a vectorial space, and such $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is an application form $X$ in $\Bbb R$ such that: 
I) $\Vert x \Vert \ge 0 \space \forall x$ in $X$, and $\Vert x \Vert = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$; 
II) $\Vert \lambda x \Vert= \vert \lambda \vert \Vert x \Vert \space \forall x$ in $X$ and $\forall \lambda$ in $\Bbb R$; 
III)$\Vert x+y \Vert \le \Vert x \Vert + \Vert y \Vert \space \forall x,y$ in $\Bbb R$.

(b) Given a metric space $(X,d)$ , and $K \subseteq X$, an open cover of $K$ is a open family of $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $X$ such that: 
$K \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} {A_i}$

Given a metric space $(X,d)$, a subset $K \subseteq X$ is called compact in all every open cover of $K$ have a finite cover: 
$K \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} {A_i} \space \Rightarrow \exists\{A_1,...,A_m\} \subset \{A_i\} : K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^m {A_i}.$

Given a metric space $(X,d)$, a subset $K \subseteq X$ is called compact for sequence if for every $\{x_n\}$ in $K$ it has a subsequence that convege at $x_0$ of $K$

(c) A metric space is called complete if every Cauchy sequence are converging.

Thank you in advance for any help, advice and comments.

Comment: There are something confusing in your question (maybe typos). Would you please check and clarify them?

Comment: @user65018 I'm not so good with english, but if you can point me where I have to rewrite things I will do my best.

Comment: By "derivable" do you actually mean "derivative"?

Comment: Yes i mean that

Comment: Also, by $C^1([0,1])$ do you mean "the space of functions that are differentiable on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$"? If yes, then I am not sure what it means by "and the derivatives can be extended with continuity in $[0,1]$". Would you clarify this?

Comment: If by $C^1([0,1])$ you meant "the space of continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$", then (a) can be easily checked (it is true).

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I mean that the derivability can be extended by continuity on [0,1]. So... it's the same as "the space of continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$"
I simple tried to translate what I wrote down on paper. I'm sorry >.<

Comment: (b) is false.

**Proof.** Given the norm (and also metric) $\|\cdot\|_{c^1}$, for each sequence of functions $\{u_n\}\subseteq C^1([0,1])$, it has a convergent subsequence (here the convergence must be uniform given the sup-norm) if and only if $\{u_n\}$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, according to **Ascoli-Arzela theorem**. Here it is easy to find a sequence in $C^1([0,1])$ that is not even bounded. Therefore, there exists some sequence which does not have any convergent subsequence, which implies that $C^1([0,1])$ is not compact. $\square$

Comment: (c) is true, but the proof is tedious. Basically the proof is the same as proving that "$(C([0,1]), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is complete. I guess you know how to do this.

Comment: Ok, thank you, can you give some hint, I'm not yet good with demonstration.

Comment: A compact space cannot have an infinite closed discrete subspace. For $n\in \mathbb N\cup \{0\}$ and $x\in [0,1]$ let $f_n(x)=n.$  Consider the subspace $\{f_n: n\in \mathbb N\cup \{0\}\}$..... An even simpler argument: If $(X, d) $ is a  compact metric space then $\sup\{d(p,q):p,q\in X\}<\infty.$  Consider $\sup \{\|nf -f_0\|:n \in \mathbb N\}$ for any non-zero $f\in C^1[0,1]$.